# Deploying context.xml to webapps/[webappname]/META-INF

Tags: tomcat, ant, build.xml

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.26 and am writing build.xml to deploy war file. The following code is what I have right now, and I need to pack context.xml under /META-INF/ as I wish to have [this configuration like #2](http://spdn.ifas.ufl.edu/docs/deployer-howto.html#A%20word%20on%20Contexts). I have searched the attribute for the war command, but I couldn't find anything that works like *webxml* for WEB-INF/web.xml.

So my questions are,

1) Is there an war attribute to place the context.xml under META-INF ?

2) If there isn't such an attribute, what would be the best way to place the context.xml under META-INF for each webapp?

```
<target name="packwar">
   <war destfile="${appname}.war" webxml="web.xml">
        <lib file="${bin}/myapp.jar"/>
   </war>
</target>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`metainf`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) nested element of the 'war' task:

> The nested metainf element specifies a
>   FileSet. All files included in this
>   fileset will end up in the META-INF
>   directory of the war file. If this
>   fileset includes a file named
>   MANIFEST.MF, the file is ignored and
>   you will get a warning.

Something like this:

```
<target name="packwar">
   <war destfile="${appname}.war" webxml="web.xml">
        <lib file="${bin}/myapp.jar"/>
        <metainf file="context.xml" />
   </war>
</target>
```

There is a  similar option - 'webinf' - for deploying to the WEB-INF directory.